# How to run selenium webdriver inside a docker-in-docker?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci-runner, selenium-grid, docker-in-docker

I'm using Gitlab runners which are all defined as "docker in docker". It means they're not installed on a machine's bare metal but rather run inside a docker on the machine.
Those runners can run containers inside of them, hence the name docker in docker.
What I'm trying to do is to bring up this selenium webdriver docker container selenium/standalone-chrome and connect to it.
The problem is that even after the internal Selenium container runs I can't access it on localhost (i.e. the internal network of the hosting container).
How should I define it?